# Is is safe to use HSQLDB for production? (JBoss AS5.1)

Tags: java, jboss5.x, hsqldb

The JBoss developers warn against the use of HSQLDB as a persistent storage (see [JBoss wiki](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HypersonicProduction)). I am confused though, because HSQLDB appears to be used heavily in production.

Especially, the above mentioned page seems to warn against the use of HSQLDB *entirely* and not against the use in conjunction with JBoss.

Is it still not recommendable to use HSQLDB in JBoss (particularly, the bundled default datasource in Community JBoss 5.1)?

*:We plan to use it in in-memory mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your own link doesn't convince you, then consider that using it in in-memory mode can lead to undesirable effects when JMS queues get backed up -- JBoss will start trying to persist the messages to the backing store to free heap space, but that won't actually help.  Soon, you're spinning in GC or throwing OOM exceptions.

Comment: I see the point. But ensuring that the messages are not retried infinitely, giving it enough heap space etc., that risk can basically be removed, right?

Comment: Maybe... if you're confident that all of the code in your application will be held to the same high standard, even after you're gone and it's being maintained by someone who doesn't know anything about hypersonic and its pitfalls.
It seems like you're motivated to keep HSQLDB for some reason; maybe there's another question in there.

Comment: Hmmm... I'll give it a good thought one more time. Thanks for the advice!