# What is the performance of HSQLDB with several clients

Tags: hsqldb, database-performance

I would like to use HSQLDB +Hibernate in a server with 5 to 30 clients that will fairly intensively write to the DB.
Each client will persist a dozen thousands lines in a single table every 30 seconds (24/7, that's roughly 1 billion rows/day), and the clients will also query the database for a few thousands lines more or less at random times at an average frequency of a couple of requests every 5 to 10 seconds.

Can HSQLDB handle such a use case or should I switch to MySQL/PostgreSQL ?

Answer (score 4):

You are looking at a total of 2000 - 12000 writes and 5000 - 30000 reads per second.

With fast hardware, HSQLDB can probably handle this with persistent memory tables. With CACHED tables, it may be able to handle the lower range with solid state disks (disk seek time is the main parameter).

See this test. You can run it with MySQL and PostgresSQL for comparison.

http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlPerformanceTests.html

Answer (score -3):

You should switch. HSQLDB is not for critical apps. Be prepared for data corruption and decreasing startup performance over time.

The main negative hype comes from JBoss: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HypersonicProduction

See also http://www.coderanch.com/t/89950/JBoss/HSQLDB-production

Also see similar question: [Is is safe to use HSQLDB for production? (JBoss AS5.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299080/is-is-safe-to-use-hsqldb-for-production-jboss-as5-1)

Comment: Well, that page is obsolete. At that time HSQLDB had no transactional isolation. Nowadays, it is supposed to handle transactions much better. We actually DO use HSQLDB successfully for a critical app, but embedded. Now my question is for server mode.

Comment: Well, the asker has been warned.

Comment: Also, no matter how HSQLDB treats transactions, in-memory tables not assuring persistence atomicly after transaction ends is imo not for production.

Comment: @Ondra HSQLDB has disk based modes and can persist data on commit.

Comment: Before you downvote, here is the the answer: "Very late, but with more experience, I can now confidently answer that there is no chance HSQLDB could fit the requirements. This is a job for a highly optimized, client-server DB engine."